# Bad Request Error after creation of payment

Tags: node.js

After trying payment-creation API Of Razorpay below Error response is getting

```
Error: { code: 'BAD_REQUEST_ERROR',
     description: 'Payment failed. Please contact site admin',
     field: 'amount' } }
Request :
     { amount: 1000, // in currency subunits. Here 1000 = 1000 paise, which equals to ₹10
      currency: 'INR',// Default is INR. We support more than 90 currencies.
      email: 'test12@test.com',
      contact: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
      order_id: 'order_EFRPoaGqJF0jMR',
      method: 'netbanking',
      bank: 'HDFC'
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific with the issue, share some code snippets and format your question so it's more readable. Help us help you!

Answer (score 0):

I got answer of my question. The amount passing through request is more than 10 ₹.